# KStreams app - excessive memory usage

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Im running a (relatively) simple KStreams app:

> stream->aggregate by key->filter->foreach

It processes ~200K records / minute on AWS EC2 with 32Gb  / 8CPU

Within 10 minutes of starting it the memory usage exceeds 40%. Not long after (typically less than 15min) the OS will OOM-kill it.

Configuration:

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "450000");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 250);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
config.put(StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, EventTimeExtractor.class.getName());

config.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
config.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, "2");
```

Aggregation step:

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, String> ktAgg = sourceStream.groupByKey().aggregate(
        String::new,
        new Aggregate(),
        TimeWindows.of(20 * 60 * 1000L).advanceBy(5 * 60 * 1000L).until(40 * 60 * 1000L),
        stringSerde, "table_stream");
```

Using Kafka 0.10.1.1

Suggestions on where to look for the culprit?

---

### side note:

I tried instrumenting this app with **NewRelic** javaagent. When I ran it with `-XX:+useG1GC` it did the standard "use lots of memory and then get killed" *but* when I removed the G1GC param the process ran up System Load to > 21. I had to kill that one myself.

What output there was from NewRelic didn't show anything outrageous w/re memory mgmt.

Comment: Hi, i have an example that is very similar to what you have above and i am not seeing any memory issues. Are you sure there isn't something else in your app causing this problem?

Comment: Im fairly convinced the problem is in my code - I just can't seem to find it. Ive tried different serdes, time windows and anything else I could think of.